# linq to sql vb.net case statements to add other test

Tags: vb.net, linq

It there a way to add other test to may request :

```
Dim exceptBanned = (From c In query _
Where Not bannedCCList.Contains(c.Field(Of String)("N°Reçu")) _
      Group c By c!code_projet _
      Into nb = Count(CInt(c("code_projet"))), ca = Sum(CDec(c("Prix") + CDec(c("tva")))) _
      Select nb, ca).ToList
```

I want to add other test to my query , below what i have tried but  unfortunately it doesn't work :

```
   If tf = 1 Then
    exceptBanned = exceptBanned.Where(Function(c) c!type.Equals("Transfert 
    acompte") = False) 
else
   exceptBanned = exceptBanned.Where(Function(c) c!type.Equals("Transfert 
    acompte") = True) 
end if
```

Thank in advance

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a proper description for an error or unexpected result.

Comment: It give me an syntaxe error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issus ,and i'd like to share this solution here :

```
  Dim qryResultsDes = (From order In GlobalDataDesistement.AsEnumerable() _
 Where order!code_projet = tab.Rows(i).Item("code_projet"))

  If tf = 1 Then
    qryResultsDes = qryResultsDes .Where(Function(c) c!type.Equals("Transfert 
    acompte") = False) 
else
   qryResultsDes = qryResultsDes .Where(Function(c) c!type.Equals("Transfert 
    acompte") = True) 
end if


Dim exceptBanned = (From c In qryResultsDes _
Where Not bannedCCList.Contains(c.Field(Of String)("N°Reçu")) _
      Group c By c!code_projet _
      Into nb = Count(CInt(c("code_projet"))), ca = Sum(CDec(c("Prix") + CDec(c("tva")))) _
      Select nb, ca).ToList
```